# Interface Listener From Parent Fragment to Tabs Fragment Not Working

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-tabs

I am trying to implement interface listener for my parent fragment to Tabs Fragment. Its giving Null value error.
Here is my code.
In given below code I have Created interface with name OnFeedItemClickListener and trying to override the method into tabs fragment.

parent_fragment.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="bottom|end"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            android:orientation="horizontal">


            <Button
                android:id="@+id/ButtonId"
                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Switch"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

        </LinearLayout>
        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            app:tabMode="fixed"/>


        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" >
    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

fragment_one.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF">


    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/navigation" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

ParentFragment.java

```
public class ParentFragment extends Fragment implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    private List<Fragment> fragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<String> titleList = new ArrayList<>();
    private View rootView;
    private ViewPager viewPager;
   private TextTabsAdapter adapter;
    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    private Button BtnId;


    private OnFeedItemClickListener onFeedItemClickListener;

    public ParentFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }




    private void initialise() {
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) rootView.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        toolbar.setTitle("Dashboard");
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                getActivity(), drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        drawer.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.whiteColor));
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        viewPager = (ViewPager) rootView.findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
        tabLayout = (TabLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    }
    private void prepareDataResource() {

            addData(new FragmentOne(), "ONE");
            addData(new FragmentTwo(), "TWO");

    }


    private void addData(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        fragmentList.add(fragment);
        titleList.add(title);
    }



    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.parent_fragment, container, false);

        initialise();
        prepareDataResource();

        adapter = new TextTabsAdapter(getChildFragmentManager(), fragmentList, titleList);

        // Bind Adapter to ViewPager.
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

        // Link ViewPager and TabLayout
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        BtnId = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.CountryId);

        BtnId.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                onFeedItemClickListener.onButtonClick();
            }
        });
        return rootView;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        return false;
    }




    public void setOnFeedItemClickListener(OnFeedItemClickListener onFeedItemClickListener) {
        this.onFeedItemClickListener = onFeedItemClickListener;
    }


    public interface OnFeedItemClickListener {
        void onButtonClick();


    }
}
```

FragmentOne.java

```
public class FragmentOne extends Fragment implements FeedsAdapter.OnFeedItemClickListener,ParentFragment.OnFeedItemClickListener{


    private RecyclerView mrecyclerview;
    private FeedsAdapter feedadapter;
    View rootView;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        rootView =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);
        mrecyclerview = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        mrecyclerview.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));


        populateFeedsData();
        ParentFragment parentFragment = new ParentFragment();
        parentFragment.setOnFeedItemClickListener(this);

        return rootView;
    }


    @Override
    public void onButtonClick() {
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "ButtonClicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Please help me out solving this problem many a thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your **FragmentOne** class, you are creating a new instance of **ParentFragment**.

```
ParentFragment parentFragment = new ParentFragment();
```

What you actually need to do is to get that instance of the **ParentFragment** that created the FragmentOne child fragment.

To do that you can try this :

```
ParentFragment parentFrag = ((ParentFragment)FragmentOne.this.getParentFragment());
```

And now you can call the setOnFeedItemClickListener() function through **parentFrag**.

Hope it helps!

Comment: from where ChildFragment came from? is ChildFragment is FragmentOne? when I am adding your code ChildFragment displaying in error(red alert) format

Comment: one more thing it is working for only one fragment tab not for another one fragment when I am overriding the method in two different fragment tab one and tab two

Comment: the setOnFeedItemClickListener() in ParentFragment sets only one listener instance at a time, so it works with only one child fragment. what you can do is either use two listeners or call setOnFeedItemClickListener() every time you change the fragment, that is when you shift tabs!

Comment: Can you give an example to call setOnFeedItemClickListener() ?on changing fragment please  as I am on fragment one but when I am clicking on that button its affecting fragment two instead of fragment one

Comment: put your app on debug mode and check when you shift tabs, does the onCreateView of respective fragments get called?